# Winforms VLC Player Streaming Image Distortion

Tags: winforms, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I m using Vlc player in my winforms application and it generally works fine. But time to time video image is distorted (right image) Anyone has solution for this ? I also checked MediaPlayerEncounteredError event but it also doesnt throw. [image: image is distorted]

Im using Vlc.Net.Forms V 2.1.126 nuget package

Comment: Maybe your network is too slow at times? Are your graphic card drivers up to date? Can you reproduce in VLC? Can you reproduce when disabling hardware decoding?

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean by saying "disabling hardware decoding". How can I try it?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say the version of libvlc you were using.

Considering the age of that Vlc.DotNet version, I assume that you are using a 2.x version of libvlc, which is quite old now, and only has software decoding, which could lead to lost frames etc...

Try to install a newer VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows NuGet package and see if the issue persists.

You can also try to enable logs with the `-vv` option and see what's going on, you could try to increase network buffering...

Also check your network connectivity. It may be caused by lost packets at the network level.

Comment: I just couldnt understand few things

1- I add this vlc module from toolbox( I activated it from COM Components) 
Com Components it writes that VLCActivex Plugin and IE Web Pugin2 v 1.0.0.0

2- I downloaded latest NUGET package of VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows 3.0.8.1 

3- After this operation the VLCActivexPlugin version did not change at com components moreover I couldnt see library at references.

Comment: just adding that nuget package would be enough ?    How to enable logs(-vv) option and increase netwrk buffering at c# side because I couldnt see any property which sets buffer.

Comment: Using the VLC ActiveX is not supported anymore. you must reference LibVLCSharp or VLC.DotNet in your project. I'd recommend LibVLCSharp